# How do I sheathe my weapons in Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

So I'm currently in the Boyle Estate party and people keep telling me to put my weapons away, but I've no idea how.

I've had a quick look through the controls to see if there is a way to bind a button, but there doesn't seem to be. It must be possible as after cutscenes your weapons are automatically sheathed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To sheathe your weapons, hold the "Use" button.  By default, this is <kbd>F</kbd> on the PC, <kbd>◻</kbd> on the PS3 and <kbd>X</kbd> on the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: This really should have been mentioned in the game!